# If a user has a female avatar, will their question receive more attention?

Tags: discussion, questions, gender

I have noticed quite a few questions lately where the avatar of the poster was decidedly female (even if their handle was ambiguous). I have also noticed a tendency for these questions to get more answers even if the question is poor.

I'm interested in if this effect exists and if so how pronounced it is. It's an important question because it's arguable that the increased attention for women's questions can be a positive boost at a time when many people are trying to get more women into computer science; but it's also arguable that it's sexist and enabling them to ask poor questions.

---

EDIT: Anecdotal evidence: [Using PHP to update records in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35781512/1011527)

Note the post is code only, no question is ever asked. Two answers and a boatload of comments. The avatar and the name reflect that the OP is female (I know we cannot determine the truthiness of that, we can only speculate on who the actual poster is). It has received (at this time) 3 close votes, 2 voted as unclear and 1 as "why doesn't the code work".

Comment: I am *less* inclined to answer a post if the avatar is of an overtly female model, actually. Colour me suspicious. :-)

Comment: Madam, I'm not even going to respond to this.

Comment: This question could be answered by A/B (or better M/F) testing, I think.

Comment: I really hope not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree there. It kinda bugs me that I even look, but I *strongly* suspect there are plenty of people who believe (right or wrong) that having an attractive female avatar will get them better/more answers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber which is why these profiles typically have a ton of views.

Comment: I was wondering this myself. I've been seeing a lot of avatars that just don't fit - sometimes a DEFINITE non-native speaker would have an avatar that was *clearly* an American "girl-next-door".

Comment: There was one female a while ago who got a lot of profile views for some illogical reason. She didn't get better (what we should be measuring this on) better answers. Other than that I really haven't noticed a difference. If the question is interesting you win, no matter your promulgated gender.

Comment: I know it's not intended that way, but "Or is that we're all surprised, as nerds, that women would be in our midst?" ends up being sexist in and of itself since it assumes that "we all" is speaking to an exclusively male audience here on SO. Having said that, getting more women to join the tech world is a complex problem, and I don't believe that the fact that low quality questions get answers has any bearing on it whatsoever. Can you elaborate on your premise? How is answering less than stellar questions a disservice in light of a push towards gender diversity?

Comment: Yeah, @Ben; I suspect there might be a tendency in a certain direction vis-a-vis quality of knowledge for people who would answer based on such a thing...

Comment: Your head is WAY too pointy for me, @Gracchus

Comment: Says the Unitato @AndrewBarber?

Comment: My apologies @AnnaLear, the nerd thing was meant to be humorous though I can now see where it really wasn't. As for answering less than stellar questions: there is a push on SO to make sure that posters ask good questions (well formatted, supported by code that was attempted, etc.) and if gender diversity is the goal all posters would be treated the same in terms of advice on making their questions better and searching to make sure the answer doesn't exist already instead of being patronizing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah, so you're supposing that posters with overtly female avatars or names don't get as much ... encouragement to improve their posts and instead just get answers? (Also, no offense taken.)

Comment: @Bart [Related](https://twitter.com/AndrewLBarber/status/466553244391854080)

Comment: I'm very much in favor of positive discrimination. Now go upvote all my answers.

Comment: It would seem so @AnnaLear. At least in the few that I have noticed over the past several days.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Your presumption that the audience here (intended or not) is male was discussed at length in this meta post -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222024/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral

Comment: There's actually a frequent user from Brazil with a female avatar, who explicitly states in his profile that he's not female, and that the avatar is just as a fun "joke" to see what kind of responses he gets.

Comment: The [White Knight Syndrome](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=White%20Knight%20Syndrome) is a documented phenomenon on the internet already, it is reasonable to assume that StackExchange "suffers" from this as much as any other internet destination. Is it a problem? I don't think it is. It seems slightly patronizing to presume that a female developer's only avenue for improvement is through guidance from men on SO. Advancement, or lack thereof, is less a product of one's gender influence on online interactions and more a reflection of one's personal ambition and capacity.

Comment: It's human nature -- if a poster is perceived female "she" will likely be given more slack, be talked down to to a degree, and generally attract more (friendly) attention.  A few misogynists will, of course "help" to "balance" things out.  But like I said, it's simply human nature, and probably one of the more harmless such behaviors here.

Comment: FYI, I finally found that one user with the female avatar [that I was talking about earlier](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254891/do-you-think-that-the-perceived-sex-of-the-poster-factors-into-whether-less-than/254894#comment21319_254891), [here ***he*** is!](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1090562/salvador-dali).

Comment: It's not really opinioned based? You could easily create a research study on it, and not even a very complicated or deep one.

Comment: I rewrote this pretty heavily to get to the objective question. Asking whether women's questions *should* receive more attention is on the one hand opinion based, but it *could* make for a good meta SO question, if asked as a matter of recommendation or policy. I'm unsure about that; and it would be a challenging question to write well, but I invite the OP or someone to try in a separate question and I can help.

Comment: @Chris I lost it at "documented" with a link to Urban Dictionary.

Comment: @corsiKa Thanks for refusing to accept information based on a domain name. Does the website with [Psychology Today](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-white-knight-syndrome/200906/the-overly-empathic-white-knight) on it hold more credibility for you? How about an [incidental mention](http://www.businessweek.com/autos/autobeat/archives/2006/12/white_knight_syndrome.html) in an unrelated business article, does that convince you that the term exists (the original purpose of the link)? Hope this helps you move past the red herring so you can think about the actual issue under discussion.

Comment: Wow, sorry to piss in your poutine. I've been on the internet long enough to know it's a thing, I just found it funny that UD counted as documentation. And if you'll notice, I've meaningfully contributed to the "actual issue under discussion" on an answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited to cognitive sciences SE :D

Answer (score 7):

Is it a factor? Probably - both in positive and negative ways.

Should it be a factor? Probably not. Sometimes I wonder if we get so focused on how [x] is treated, we end up just shifting patterns and creating new problems around [x].

In heath care, there are far more female nurses than male nurses - and the male nurses are treated differently. However, there isn't nearly the same frenzy to get a more "gender equitable distribution" of nurses.

Back to programming - I assume everyone is lying with their handle and avatar and just look at the question/answer. ;)

Comment: `Probably not` - you misspelled `No`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Point taken, though there are a few related debates that - depending on the outcome - would influence the appropriateness of [yes|no] for the individual. E.g.: To help encourage more female programmers, we should focus on coaching more female visitors. If you agree, then the sex of the poster should be a factor how you work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - But that's just adding a new dimension to <s>argue</s> debate and get distracted by.

Comment: What I'm saying - and perhaps you missed it - is that the gender of the asker unequivocally does not change the way you answer the question. If it does, then there is probably a problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I did get the point, and I agree that it really should just be a [meets|doesn't meet] quality standard, and the answer a question gets is the answer you feel the question deserves. Period - regardless of the asker. But that's just me - there are tangential debates that would influence some people based on where they fall. Could they be legit mitigating factors? Hell if I know - hence the "probably not". All part of what likely should have been a more nuanced answer than I could jot out on a mobile keyboard. Maybe I'll update when I get home. :)

Comment: You asked "Should it be a factor?" and said "Probably not." While it *may be a factor* for some people, it absolutely, 100%, *should not be*. To me, saying "probably not" suggests that you agree that maybe, in some cases or to some degree, gender should be a factor. That needs to be called out (or corrected) IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

This would be an interesting question to research, but I see a few potential pitfalls.

- You'd have to come up with a list of users who have female avatars. Automating this would be a project of its own.
- You'd have to come up with some kind of quality metric for questions. Votes wouldn't be valid, since the same tendency that you're trying to study, the one that's making us answer questions from female posters in higher proportions, could presumably be having an effect on voting as well. This would also be a project of its own.
- There could very well be some other factor that's causing some low-quality questions to get more answers than others. (Example: Maybe just having a *human* name and avatar has a positive effect over just leaving the default user name and image, and you're only noticing the trend when you see a female avatar.) This is a surmountable problem, but you'd have to allow for it in your study.

Comment: Detecting *human* names is barely surmountable on its own.

Comment: Agreed @FrédéricHamidi and I hadn't really noticed the connection of a human name along with a female avatar.

Comment: Research you say? Step 1.) Change your profile pic to a female. Step 2.) Track the profile views.

Comment: @Kermit I already get a lot of profile views. I can only conclude that nerds love gawking at pictures of naked cartoon lizards.

Comment: who doesn't want to see a naked cartoon lizard?

Comment: You don't need a list of all users. Take a random sample.

Comment: Possible metrics - time until first answer or comment or edit. Yes it's statistically complex but by no means insurmountable.

Comment: Also the frog is right. You can just test this using an old fashioned experiment, instead of doing a statistical study.

Comment: @djechlin I didn't say a list of *all* users. Making a list isn't the hard part. Finding ones with female avatars is. Taking a random sample doesn't help that in the slightest.

Comment: It does just because you can manually decide on a finite sample. Yes this will need to be properly documented in the study.

Comment: @djechlin That's not a random sample then. Your (and Kermit's) other comment might be on to something though. You could do an experiment just by replacing avatars (and maybe names?) at random with ones taken from a pool of female photos, then see what changes (views, votes, comments, answers, etc.).

Comment: No, *sample* the users randomly, *decide* which are which manually. I'm not saying it will be 50/50, but it will be proportionate to the population as a whole.

Comment: The real way to test would be to track question attention for people with regular avatars, and then give them female avatars and see if the question attention remains the same. And vice versa, those with regular female avatars have it change. That would be the real way to test because you'd be working as few altered variables as possible.